# Proper way to send post request using Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, request-promise

I dont know if I am properly using the promise, the problem here is that sending request is too long.

This is my current code

```
exports.updatePostApi = async (datas) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(async () => {
      let api = "user/update?_method=PUT";
      let data = new FormData();
      let result = {};
      data.append("userbody", JSON.stringify(datas));
      console.log(data._valueLength + data._overheadLength + 56, "length");
      const config = {
        method: "post",
        baseURL: apiEndpoint,
        url: api,
        data: data,
        headers: {
          "BIR-Authorization": Authorization,
          "Content-Type": `multipart/form-data; boundary=${data._boundary}`,
          "Content-Length": data._valueLength + data._overheadLength + 56,
        },
        maxBodyLength: Infinity,
        maxContentLength: Infinity,
      };

      return await axios(config);

      console.log(result);
      resolve(result);
    }, 5000);
  });

};
```

Comment: This code is after `return` and will never run `resolve(result)`

Comment: how to solve it?

Comment: `resolve(axios(config))` instead of the return line and 2 next

Comment: `new Promise(async (resolve, reject)` is always an anti-pattern ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I shortened your code and return the promise of axios so one can `result = await updatePostApi(data)`

```js
exports.updatePostApi = async (datas) => {
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000))

      let data = new FormData();
      data.append("userbody", JSON.stringify(datas));
      
      return axios({
        method: "post",
        baseURL: apiEndpoint,
        url: "user/update?_method=PUT",
        data: data,
        headers: {
          "BIR-Authorization": Authorization,
          "Content-Type": `multipart/form-data; boundary=${data._boundary}`,
          "Content-Length": data._valueLength + data._overheadLength + 56,
        },
        maxBodyLength: Infinity,
        maxContentLength: Infinity,
      });
};
```

Comment: `dropped the 5 sec delay` perhaps that was important :p - `await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000))` at the top of the function will put the delay back in though :p

Comment: sure I'll add it back in